# Intra/interal/external cross validation

Tags: cross-validation

I'm wondering if someone could help me out telling me the difference between intra, internal and external cross validation. In literature it seems that there is in particular no distinction between intra and interal. Thank's a lot in advance!

MLearning

Comment: The following is just a guess and not assured: Intra: is the "classical" way of cross-validation for example with the k-fold method. Internal: use of new data for a known class External: means that data of classes are used that has not been seen before I hope thats right and I will use this definition in a final exam tomorrow. Is it possible that you are attending the same exam?

Comment: Welcome to cross validated. Can you give a source where you came across these terms?